# Automatically display UIImagePickerController on application load

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Currently, my app loads a UIImagePickerController when a button is pressed. I would like to get rid of the button and have it load automatically when the view loads and then have the app close after an image is selected.

This is the method I have been using for when the button is clicked.

```
-(BOOL)startMediaBrowserFromViewController:(UIViewController *)controller usingDelegate:(id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>)delegate
{
if(([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
   || (delegate == nil)
   || (controller == nil))
    return NO;
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

[controller presentModalViewController:mediaUI animated: YES];
return YES;
}
```

I figured I could just call this method in the loadView method. I tried three ways. First, the obvious one.

```
[self startMediaBrowserFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self]
```

That didn't work, but still returned YES which I found odd.

Next, I called the method that is used when the button is clicked.

```
[self btnShowClicked:nil]
```

No luck there either. Finally, I tried one that I thought would have to work, since it would be simulating a touch on the button (if I understand it correctly)

```
[self.btnShow sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Still no luck and I'm out of ideas.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I don't think it should be that difficult.

Comment: Try to call it in the viewDidLoad method - some things are not available yet in the loadView method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your code (any of the three methods you tried - the first looks fine) to your `viewDidAppear` method instead of in `loadView`.  Make sure to also call `[super viewDidAppear]` first.

The problem relies on `[controller presentModalViewController:mediaUI animated: YES];` being called *after* everything is set up properly.

Comment: You could just place the call into viewDidAppear method and just wait for it to be called by the system

Comment: Well yes, but that's poorly encapsulated!  What if he wanted to call it again later?  Manually calling viewDidAppear again is poor form.